# Disk-based alternative to APC?

Tags: php, caching, apc

I really like the ease of implementation and functionality of PHP's APC caching module. In a website I'm working on, I've been using it to cache json responses from a remote server (for inventory, etc). However, I'm now doing a number of different requests (several thousand), which I'd like to cache, and I'm wary of wasting memory for this purpose.

I know I *could* write some MYSQL handlers to store the results in a database, but it seems that this would be a rather large investment of my time, particularly if a way to avoid it already exits.

Comment: "and I'm wary of wasting memory for this purpose" --- facts, not the wariness should drive your development. Never follow irrational ideas when you develop.

Comment: Disks are slow.  Memory is fast.  A disk-based cache for frequently used data may well be slower than just retrieving the data to begin with.  Just dedicate the memory to it, in memcached if not APC.

Answer (score 2):

I hate to be the sound of reason, but what's wrong with something like (well, I realize it's very over simplified and should have checks in case the file is still being written while it's getting read):

```
function get_json($id) {
    $fn = './json-cache/' . $id . '.json';
    if(file_exists($fn)) {
        return file_get_contents($fn);
    } 

    $json = do_something_to_get_json();
    file_put_contents($fn, $json, LOCK_EX);
    return $json;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's all depends on how many requests you need to cache and why you need to cache them. If it's just a few, caching them in memory via something like Memcached would be really simple (and temporary). Additionally, you can set the amount of RAM that memcached uses so as to not run the box out of memory.

If you're just caching for speed, pulling them back off of drive isn't going to be all that much faster than re-polling the webservice.

If you're caching for persistence (in the case that the webservice you're polling goes down), you're best off using something like MySQL or even MongoDB. Using Mongo in particular would be nice because you wouldn't need a schema and could just jam the JSON objects into a collection and pull them back out later.

Comment: it does seem to make a huge difference in speed

Answer (score 0):

Well to answer my own question, [Pear:Cache-Lite](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.caching.cache-lite.intro.php) does the trick.